# Nginx multiple server blocks pointing to one website

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

Trying to host multiple websites on DO droplet(Ubuntu). I have the project folders in user/home because they're not static websites. the LBoard(website 1) runs on 8080 and bryanbravo.com(website 2) runs on 8081. I have both domains pointing to the the droplet ip address. **The problem is** both domains go to website 1. Do i have to use a proxy?
Here my config files
for website 1

```
server {

    listen 8080;
    server_name lboard.us;
}
```

for website 2

```
server {

    listen 8081;
    server_name bryanbravo.com;
}
```

Comment: Is that your whole config for both websites?

Comment: I had website 1 working on the default file but removed website 1 all together. But website 2 is that, but now points localhost:8080

Comment: Well, you don't set the `root` directive so I am assuming you have a conf somewhere saying all sites default to website 1.

Comment: are you refering to the nginx.conf file?

Comment: also in the sites-enabled file: perhaps this is the issue?                          
    43          location / {
    44           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    45          proxy_http_version 1.1;
    46          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    47          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    48          proxy_set_header Host $host;
    49          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    50          }